# Python WHILE loop, struggle to understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I just want to rearrange the list from min to the max

```
mylist = [4,7,5,1,8,2,3]
result = []

while len(result) != len(mylist):

    for num in mylist:
        if num in result:
            continue
        if num == min(mylist):
            result.append(num)
            continue
    break

print(result)

result = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: Remove `break`, it has no business in your loop.

Comment: `result = sorted([4,7,5,1,8,2,3])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `min` function to get the smallest number in the list while there are items in `mylist`:

```
mylist = [4,7,5,1,8,2,3] 
result = []

while len(mylist) > 0:
    minNum = min(mylist)
    result.append(minNum)
    mylist.remove(minNum)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Or, just make `result` a copy of `mylist`, then sort it:

```
mylist = [4,7,5,1,8,2,3] 
result = mylist
result.sort()

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

After you have found the minimum number and added to the new list, you also need to remove it from the original list, or a copy of it.

Otherwise the min function will always return 1.

And you can change the condition in the while loop to continue until all items have been removed from mylist.

Comment: no wonder I always get "1"  . Thank you for the explanation sir.